# How to modify Prolog query default output

Tags: prolog

I am using SWI-Prolog.

How can I prevent showing

```
X = jack and X = annie
```

and only print what's inside `writef()` ?

Query:

```
a(F) :-
  b(F),
  writef("%t is okay...",[F]).
```

Example:

```
a(X).
```

Output:

```
jack is okay...
X = jack,
annie is okay...
X = annie.
```

Comment: You asked Prolog a query `a(X)` so of course it will tell you what `X` makes it succeed. If you don't want `X`, don't provide it. Just get rid of the argument to `a/1`: `a :- b(F), ...` and call it with `a`, not `a(X)`.

Comment: or call it using an anonymous variable: `?- a(_).`